# Why dont font formats imported from Github function correctly?

Tags: css, github, fonts, font-face, font-family

Using canvas to generate text for some Trading Cards (Its a community project)

And I needed the Andy Font. However there are no stable web serving locations.

So I went with github. I placed all my font formats inside this repository folder:

https://github.com/FunctFlow/TerrariaTradingCards/tree/master/andy%20font%20family

Then I used this font-font inside of my project:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: "Andy";
 src: url("https://github.com/FunctFlow/TerrariaTradingCards/raw/master/andy%20font%20family/Andy-Bold.eot");
 src: url("https://github.com/FunctFlow/TerrariaTradingCards/raw/master/andy%20font%20family/Andy-Bold.eot?#iefix")
   format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("https://github.com/FunctFlow/TerrariaTradingCards/raw/master/andy%20font%20family/Andy-Bold.woff2")
   format("woff2"),
  url("https://github.com/FunctFlow/TerrariaTradingCards/raw/master/andy%20font%20family/Andy-Bold.woff")
   format("woff"),
  url("https://github.com/FunctFlow/TerrariaTradingCards/raw/master/andy%20font%20family/Andy-Bold.ttf")
   format("truetype");
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

However, my project does NOT render the andy font, as you can see in this codepen: https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/bGVBpmj

Answer (score 0):

**I love how solutions always appear minutes after Ive given up and come here.**

Basically, Github serves the wrong filetype headers, and the website cant recognize the font-formats.

So you cannot use Github for font formats, similarly to how you cant use it to host Javascript or CSS or whatever else you need to reference through http.

The best solution I can think of is to use a tool like jsDelivr to reference the fonts. As seen here: [JsDelivr Github](https://www.jsdelivr.com/?docs=gh)

And using a link like this:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/FunctFlow/TerrariaTradingCards@master/andy%20font%20family/Andy-Bold.ttf

My fonts now render successfully

Comment: GitHub raw files aren''t intended to be used as a CDN, so GitHub may or may not serve correct `Content-Type` headers.  Even if it did, you should host your resources on a CDN or on your own site.